# JsonStore throws loadexception <i>at random</i>

Tags: extjs, combobox, jsonstore

I have the following problem: I have an Ext.data.JsonStore which populates a combobox. I get a loadexception *sometimes*. I can refresh the combobox time after time but sooner or later I get an exception. Therefore, to check for time-out problems, I added a delay on the server and now I get the exception all the time. The code:

The JsonStore:

```
var ticketStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url:'/Hour/ListTickets',
    autodestroy:true,
    totalProperty:'records',
    idProperty:'Id',
    root:'rows',
    fields:[{name:'Id'},{name:'Titel'}]
});
ticketStore.on({'loadexception':{fn:storeLoadException,scope:this}});
```

The ComboBox:

```
var ticketCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox(
            {
                fieldLabel:'Ticket',
                hiddenName:'TicketId',
                store:ticketStore,
                width:300,
                valueField:'Id',
                minChars:2,
                displayField:'Titel',
                typeAhead:false,
                forceSelection:true,
                pageSize:25,
                triggerAction:'all',
                emptyText:'Selecteer een waarde...',
                selectOnFocus:true,
                valueNotFoundText:"nitchevo",
                value:1567,
                allowBlank: false
            }
        );
```

The data:

```
    try
    {
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> returnValue = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        returnValue.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"Id", 1}, {"Titel", "IkBenTitel"}});
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7500);

        return returnValue;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

The conversion from data to Json

```
public static JsonResult JSon(this IList<Dictionary<string, object>> list)
{
    var jsonData = new
    {
        records = list.Count,
        rows = list.ToArray()
    };
    JsonResult json = JsonHelper.Json(jsonData);
    return json;
}
```

The Json-data according to Fiddler

```
{"records":1,"rows":[{"Id":1,"Titel":"IkBenTitel"}]}
```

Now with the 7.5 seconds delay I get an exception client-side when the data is supposed to arrive at the client. Without the delay I get the exception at random. The exception sees the Json data but the only description I get is 'Syntax error' which isn't helpful.

I have stripped the page of everything except the form and the store/combobox, it still happens. As you see I provide mock data so the database is not even accessed. It's driving me crazy!

I'd truly appreciate any help, I've been working on and off this for like three days! For the record, I use Internet Explorer version 8.0.7600.16385 but it also happens on Chromium.

**Update**
The bug doesn't show up in Firefox so I can't use console.

A few params from the exception
limit: 25
query: ""
start: 0
reader.ef.length: 2
jsonData.rows[0].Id: 1
jsonData.rows[0].Titel: "IkBentitel"
reader.meta.fields[0].name: "Id"
reader.meta.fields[1].name: "Titel"
reader.meta.idProperty: "Id"
reader.meta.totalProperty: "records"
reader.meta.url "/Hour/ListTickets"

If any more are required please let me know. I have also added 'args' to the exception handler and the status is 200. It puzzles me more and more...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching `loadexception`, catch the more generic `exception` from the store. `loadexception` is deprecated.  In your `exception` handler, `console.log` its parameters and update your question with the contents.  That will give us more info on why the DataProxy is throwing the exception.

```
ticketStore.on('exception', function(proxy, type, action, options, response, args) {
    console.log(proxy, type, action, options, response, args);
});
```

Details on the `exception` event params are in the [DataProxy event docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataProxy).

EDIT: I put the wrong arguments in my code sample, sorry!

Check the `type` parameter of the exception event.  It's a string and my guess is that its value is `remote` - meaning you got a valid HTTP response ( code 200, like you said ), but the reader has determined that it contains an error from the server.  Try adding in `"success": true` to your JSON response and see if that solves it.

If the value of `type` is `response` and your HTTP response isn't a 400 or 500, then the reader has determined that the response doesn't match the format it's looking for (e.g. it's missing the `idProperty` or `successProperty` that it wants).

Comment: I have added 'args' in the exception handler and the status I get is 200. The exception isn't thrown when I use Firefox, it works perfectly there.